# RabbitMQ Unack'ed messages not getting requeued

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I'm facing an issue in running RabbitMQ consumers for a long time. Several of my messages end up in an unack'ed state.

My RabbitMQ version: 3.6.15
Pika version: 0.11.0b

```
import pika
import time
import sys
import threading
from Queue import Queue
rabbitmq_server = "<SERVER>"
queue = "<QUEUE>"
connection = None

def check_acknowledge(channel, connection, ack_queue):
    delivery_tag = None
    while(True):
        try:
            delivery_tag = ack_queue.get_nowait()
            channel.basic_nack(delivery_tag=delivery_tag)
            break
        except:
            connection.process_data_events()
        time.sleep(1)


def process_message(body, delivery_tag, ack_queue):
    print "Received %s" % (body)
    print "Waiting for 600 seconds before receiving next ID\n"
    start = time.time()
    elapsed = 0
    while elapsed < 10:
        elapsed = time.time() - start
        print "loop cycle time: %f, seconds count: %02d" %(time.clock(), elapsed)
        time.sleep(1)
    ack_queue.put(delivery_tag)




def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    global connection
    ack_queue = Queue()
    t = threading.Thread(target=process_message, args=(body, method.delivery_tag, ack_queue))
    t.start()
    check_acknowledge(ch, connection, ack_queue)

while True:
    try:
        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host=rabbitmq_server))
        channel = connection.channel()
        print ' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C'
        channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
        channel.basic_consume(callback, queue=queue)
        channel.start_consuming()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

channel.close()
connection.close()
exit(0)
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Rather than use `BlockingConnection` I recommend reviewing the [async consumer example code](http://pika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/asynchronous_consumer_example.html). The method name `check_acknowledge` contradicts both your problem description as well as what it is doing (`basic_nack`) which confused me at first. You do not give enough information to help - how many of these consumers are running? How are messages being published? What rate? If you nack every single message your queues will grow unbounded so I assume there is something else you are not describing here.

Comment: Your program needs to periodically reset its connection. When that happens, the unacked messages will be requeued and reprocessed. This just happens over time with dynamic decoupled systems, there is no avoiding it.

Comment: @theMayer: How to do that in this case? Can you refer a sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following multi-threaded consumer to solve this problem.

```
import pika
import time
import sys
import threading
from Queue import Queue
rabbitmq_server = "<RABBITMQ_SERVER_IP>"
queue = "hello1"
connection = None




def check_acknowledge(channel, connection, ack_queue):
    delivery_tag = None
    while(True):
        try:
            delivery_tag = ack_queue.get_nowait()
            channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag=delivery_tag)
            break
        except:
            connection.process_data_events()
        time.sleep(1)


def process_message(body, delivery_tag, ack_queue):
    print "Received %s" % (body)
    print "Waiting for 600 seconds before receiving next ID\n"
    start = time.time()
    elapsed = 0
    while elapsed < 300:
        elapsed = time.time() - start
        print "loop cycle time: %f, seconds count: %02d" %(time.clock(), elapsed)
        time.sleep(1)
    ack_queue.put(delivery_tag)




def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    global connection
    ack_queue = Queue()
    t = threading.Thread(target=process_message, args=(body, method.delivery_tag, ack_queue))
    t.start()
    check_acknowledge(ch, connection, ack_queue)

while True:
    try:
        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host=rabbitmq_server))
        channel = connection.channel()
        print ' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C'
        channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
        channel.basic_consume(callback, queue=queue)
        channel.start_consuming()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

channel.close()
connection.close()
exit(0)
```

1. The consumer `callback` function triggers a separate function `check_acknowledge` in the main thread itself. Due to this, connection and channel objects are retained in the same thread. Note that Pika is not thread-safe so we need to maintain these objects in the same thread.
2. The actual processing happens in a new thread spawned off the main.
3. Once `process_message` is done with its processing, it puts the `delivery_tag` in the queue.
4. `check_acknowledge` loops indefinitely till it finds the `delivery_tag` put in the queue by `process_message`. Once it does find, it `acks` the message and returns.

I have tested this implementation by running this consumer by `sleep`ing for 5 min, 10 mins, 30 mins and an hour. This is working very well for me.